# Why is the template function ambiguous?

Tags: c++, templates

When I compile this code I get an error saying

> call of overloaded `swap(int&, int&)` is ambiguous

but I've written only one swap function here.

Can you tell me why the function was ambiguous and what changes I need to do to run the program correctly?

```
using namespace std;

template <class T>
void swap(T& x, T& y)
{
    T temp;
    temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}

int main()
{
    int a, b;

    cout << "Enter two elements: ";

    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;

    swap(a, b);
    cout << "a is "<<a << '\t'<<"b is " << b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Why was the swapping function overloaded even though it has only only swap function?

Comment: You are "using namespace std", which gives you access to std:swap, and that is giving ambiguity to your own swap function.

Comment: It seems you're learning C++. Please stop adding `using namespace std;` in your code. It is a [terrible practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c) and the extra bit of typing it takes to qualify things with `std::` is well worth it.

Comment: The code as given should work, but will fail as soon as you include part of the standard library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
 ::swap(a,b); //use one in global namespace, which is the one you defined
```

if you would like to call the one you defined. Since `std` has also defined a `swap` function template, the compiler will search for `std namespace` if you do not use `::`.

More specifically, the parameter `a` and `b` are of type `int`, which is defined in `std namespace`, when compiler searches for `swap`, it will find both versions: the one in `std namespace` and the other you defined in `global namespace`. You need to tell compiler which one it should use explicitly, otherwise, it will lead to ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have "using namespace std;", and presumably you are including "algorithm", you have visibility of std::swap. This gives you the ambiguity that the compiler is warning you about.

The solution is either not to add "using namespace std;", or to call your own function in the unnamed namespace explicitly, by calling it as "::swap(a, b)"